# ORA-01790 (wrong datatype) for UNION of ROWIDs across dblinks

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
SELECT ROWID FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWID FROM DUAL@OTHERDB;
```

gives

`ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`

checking the version (with `select BANNER_FULL from V$VERSION`) I get `Version 19.17.0.0.0` on both databases.

I understand it's bit strange to `union` rowids across dbs, but we are splitting an existing application, and a view that uses ROWIDs that was doing a local join, now joins across dbs, causing this error.

Any ideas of causes and/or solutions?

Thanks

Comment: What does `select dump(rowid, 16) from dual` show for local and remote tables?

Comment: - local: `Typ=69 Len=10: 0,0,0,8f,0,0,5,91,0,0`
- remote: `Typ=69 Len=10: 0,0,1,2,0,40,8,22,0,0`

Answer (score 0):

Try to `cast` `ROWID`s to `VARCHAR2` datatype, e.g.

```
SQL> select cast(rowid as varchar2(30)) from dual
  2  union all
  3  select cast(rowid as varchar2(30)) from dual@dbl;

CAST(ROWIDASVARCHAR2(30))
------------------------------
AAAAB0AABAAAAOhAAA
AAAAECAABAAAAgiAAA

SQL>
```